# How to create update function data to mysql in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, crud

I've been looking for tutorials on updating mysql data, but none of it works.
I have 2 activity, the second acticity serves to update the data from the first activity.

Main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
EditText editText;
Button button;
ArrayList<Subjects> SubjectList = new ArrayList<Subjects>();
String HttpURL = "http://10.1.55.212/PHPFiles/Subjects.php";
ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
ProgressBar progressBar ;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_items_layout, SubjectList);

    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Subjects ListViewClickData = (Subjects) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", ListViewClickData.getName());
            intent.putExtra("nameCon", ListViewClickData.getCon());
            intent.putExtra("location", ListViewClickData.getLoc());
            intent.putExtra("datePro", ListViewClickData.getPro());
            intent.putExtra("dateSale", ListViewClickData.getSale());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence stringVar, int start, int before, int count) {

            listViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(stringVar.toString());
        }
    });

    new ParseJSonDataClass(this).execute();

}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        editText.setText(scanContent);
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

private class ParseJSonDataClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context context;
    String FinalJSonResult;

    public ParseJSonDataClass(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        HttpParseClass httpParseClass = new HttpParseClass(HttpURL);

        try {
            httpParseClass.ExecutePostRequest();

            if (httpParseClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                FinalJSonResult = httpParseClass.getResponse();

                if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {

                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonResult);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        Subjects subjects;

                        SubjectList = new ArrayList<Subjects>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String tempName = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();

                            String tempCon = jsonObject.getString("nameCon").toString();

                            String tempLoc = jsonObject.getString("location").toString();

                            String tempPro = jsonObject.getString("datePro").toString();

                            String tempSale = jsonObject.getString("dateSale").toString();

                            subjects = new Subjects(tempName, tempCon, tempLoc, tempPro, tempSale);

                            SubjectList.add(subjects);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, httpParseClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_items_layout, SubjectList);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }
}
```

Update Activity :

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView TextBarcode, TextCustomer, TextLocation, TextPro, TextSale;
EditText editTextComment;
Spinner spinnerNg;
Button buttonUpdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    TextBarcode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextBarcode);
    TextCustomer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextCustomer);
    TextLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextLocation);
    TextPro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextPro);
    TextSale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextSale);

    editTextComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextComment);
    spinnerNg = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerNg);
    buttonUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

    TextBarcode.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
    TextCustomer.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("nameCon"));
    TextLocation.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("location"));
    TextPro.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("datePro"));
    TextSale.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("dateSale"));

    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonUpdate) {
        updateEmployee();
    }
}

private void updateEmployee(){
    final String desg = editTextComment.getText().toString().trim();
    final String salary = spinnerNg.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

    class UpdateEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(UpdateActivity.this,"Updating...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_ID,id);
            hashMap.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_POSISI,desg);
            hashMap.put(konfigurasi.KEY_EMP_GAJIH,salary);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

            String s = rh.sendPostRequest(konfigurasi.URL_UPDATE_EMP,hashMap);

            return s;
        }
    }

    UpdateEmployee ue = new UpdateEmployee();
    ue.execute();
}
```

My Api konfigurasi.java

```
public class konfigurasi {

public static final String URL_UPDATE_EMP = "http://10.1.55.212/PHPFiles/Update.php";

public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_EMP_POSISI = "desg"; //desg itu variabel untuk posisi
public static final String KEY_EMP_GAJIH = "salary"; //salary itu variabel untuk gajih

public static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";
 }
```

My PHP :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //MEndapatkan Nilai Dari Variable
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $desg = $_POST['comment'];
    $sal = $_POST['status'];

    //import file koneksi database
    require_once('DatabaseConfig.php');

    //Membuat SQL Query
    $sql = "UPDATE datahori SET comment = '$desg', status = '$sal' WHERE id = $id;";

    //Meng-update Database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Berhasil Update Data Pegawai';
    }else{
        echo 'Gagal Update Data Pegawai';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

when i click the listview data from the first activity. it will switch directly to the second activity to perform the update process. as well as doing additional data on "editTextComment" and "spinnerNg". When i run the program and click the update button but nothing change in mysql.

any help will be appriciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the content of the message as received by your PHP?

Comment: What MySQL error do you get?

Comment: The question is not clear.Do you want to update the list view data?if this is your question do things as follow.1st get the position of the data id to modify  then pass modify id to another activity then pass the modify data along with modify data id to the change the previous data and then Write the php query to modify the MySQL data.

Comment: i already edit my question